# Find results with a certain number of fields in my MongoDB subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to query a subdocument where results must have all fields specified ***and no others***. Is this possible? And if so how?

**For example:**

I want a query like this:

```
db.users.find({ 
    "pref.no_popup": true, 
    "pref.font_large": false, 
    "pref": { "$size", 2 }});
```

To match this:

```
{
  "user": "Ed",
  "pref": {
    "no_popup": true,
    "font_large": false
  }
}
```

But not this:

```
{
  "user": "James",
  "pref": {
    "no_popup": true,
    "font_large": false,
    "font_red": true
  }
}
```

I realise the [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator is designed for arrays, so how can I do something similar for subdocuments?

Note that I did try not using a dot notation to query for exact field presence but then I had issues with ordering.

Comment: the problem you have (and with the answers below) is that you can only judge size by checking existence of a certain property which isn't good enough, I mean what if you have another property instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is this "Exact match on subdocument" scenario. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/), search in page for the quoted text.

I think that your query should be:

```
db.users.find({ 
    "pref" : {
        "no_popup" : true,
        "font_large" : false
    } });
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I hit the issue of an exact order as mentioned...the order of my queried fields needs to be dynamic, where if I use the above then half the time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [$exists operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)?

```
db.users.find({ 
    "pref.font_red" : {"$exists":false}
});
```

Comment: Another good suggestion, and one I had thought about. My issue with this is that I have a lot of potential preferences, which could result in a large list of preferences that should not exist.

Comment: Then I think you haven't choice. If they are common queries you can save them in your MongoDB shell environment to improve reutilization.

Comment: @Ed. You have also got to consider that objects are not always ordered as such and size of 2 on one document might not be a size of 2 on another

Answer (score 1):

If your have many properties that you do not wont to match, and only two that wont, you could try something like this to solve order problem (as upgrade to Andrei answer):

```
db.users.find({ $or: [
"pref" : {
    "no_popup" : true,
    "font_large" : false
},
"pref" : {       
    "font_large" : false,
    "no_popup" : true
} ] });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the closest the OP is gonna get to what he wants and soon not even this, there is JIRA to convert this notation to dot notation which means this query might not be future proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to use a mapReduce...

Not ideal, but should solve the problem.

```
mapper=function(){ for (key in this.pref){
  emit(this._id, {'count':1}); \\assume your user id is called _id
  }
}
reducer=function(k,v){ 
  counter=0; 
  for (i=0;i<v.length;i++){
    counter+=v[i].count;
  }
  return {'count':counter}
 }
```

This should give you a collection with people's IDs and the number of prefs that have been set